# Connect mongodb docker container to localhost

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-container

I am trying to bind port of docker container that is mongodb in docker to localhost. I tried doing:
`sudo docker run -p 127.0.0.1:27018:27017 mongo:3.2`

I could able to connect to it but the databases added in docker containers are not exposed to local.

I even tried of binding `0.0.0.0.` and `192.168.x.x` that is my ip address also instead of `127.0.0.1`. In all cases i am not getting the databases in mongo docker container

Answer (score 5):

If you are running the container and want to bind it to the localhost (assuming your hosts files on your host machine binds localhost to 127.0.0.1) then you can just type:

```
sudo docker run -p 27018:27017 --name mongo mongo:3.2
```

or if you want to use the 27017 port

```
sudo docker run -p 27017:27017 --name mongo mongo:3.2
```

If you want to login and don't have the mongo binaries in your host, you can type:

```
sudo docker container exec -it mongo mongo
```

Comment: All this commands are creating a new container as `mongo:3.2` and providing a interface to local at 27018. But i need a container already running in docker to access in my local

Comment: Got it actually docker containers have their own ip's i got the ip from `docker inspect CONTAINER_ID` and accessed the mongodb

Comment: So that IP is within the docker network it resides.  If you are trying to login to mongo from another container on that network, you can do it using the container's IP.  If you are have mongo binaries on you computer, you should be able to login to the container without using the container's IP address (assuming you are using the [bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge) network).  Another way you can do it is if you make you own docker network and give the container a name, you can use that name as the IP address.